# osx Kubernetes kube-vpnkit-forwarder keep starting and Can't ping CLUSTER-IP

Tags: kubernetes

osx 11.6

Kubernetes v1.21.5
[image]

Kubernetes is running, but kube-vpnkit-forwarder keep staring.

[image]

Can't ping the CLUSTER-IP
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems to me your `kube-vpnkit-forwarder` works as expected...
   The log entry `staring kube-vpnkit-forwarder` doesnt mean it hasnt started itself. Instead, it means you dont have any resources `vpnkit` should automatically expose.

From [officials](https://www.slideshare.net/Docker/kubernetes-with-docker), [**LoadBalancer and NodePort** services automatically exposed on the host with a VPNKit controller](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/kuberneteswithdocker-180620232536/95/kubernetes-with-docker-10-638.jpg?cb=1530575899)

99,999% it will show you log entries as soon as you expose your pod/deployment with `nodeport` or `LoadBalancer` type.

2. > Can't ping the CLUSTER-IP

Thats expected.
The default Kubernetes ServiceType is ClusterIp, which exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. To reach the ClusterIp from an external computer, you can open a **Kubernetes proxy** between the external computer and the cluster.

[Accessing services running on the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-services-running-on-the-cluster)

[Publishing Services (ServiceTypes)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

[image]